# Unity Firebase: How to get auth information from another app?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, authentication

I have different Unity apps under the same Firebase project. All the apps use the Firebase Authentication system in the same project. That allows users to use the same account to login on all the apps. But is there a way where I can automatically login users so they don't have to login in each app?
In others words: Can I get and share the auth information between all my apps?

I don't have a clue on how to start .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Keychain groups

You might consider using Keychain groups in iOS applications for this purpose. Firebase documentation describes [cross-app authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/single-sign-on) using a shared keychain. Additionally, you can create your own implementation using the keychain group and add authentication information to it.

This way, you can implement cross-authentication between your applications using a [keychain group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps/).

Comment: On Android, apps with the same android:sharedUserId in the manifest and signed with the same developer key can share data.
You can use this method to share Firebase auth tokens between apps.
Note: This method requires apps to be signed with the same key and have the same sharedUserId.